# GC in a spark/scala job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've inherited two spark scala jobs, which have previously been launched sequentially, but independently:

```
dse spark-submit <job1 params>
dse spark-submit <job2 params>
```

Both jobs more-or-less max out the system resources, but run successfully with the current --executor-memory/--driver-memory/--memory-fraction settings.

There is considerable overlap between the two jobs, and we would like to merge them into a single task.  It seemed reasonable to define a new App which launches each, individually:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    processJob1(args)
    processJob2(args)
}
```

Watching in the spark console, job 1 runs and completes, then job 2 begins but runs into out of memory errors.

In Java, I believe that an OOM error usually means that GC ran, and that there wasn't enough resulting free space.  Being new to spark and ignorant, this raises a few questions.

- How does spark 'scope' an Rdd? For example, shouldn't any objects
  defined in job 1 should be marked for GC  before job 2 begins? Would
  the OOM failure in this case then indicate a memory leak in job 1?
- Will scala block the workers while a GC is going on? Would it even know, or would the jobs just run more slowly?
- GC is run by the JVM.  Does this mean that something like System.gc() would only trigger a  GC on the master node? Is it possible to trigger a GC at the workers?

Comment: Each executor runs within its own JVM with it's own heap and GC.  The JVMs run independently of each other.  Without knowing the specifics of the jobs, it's hard to make any inferences on what would be causing the problems,

Comment: Are you using a single spark context for both jobs?  Are there many broadcast variables used?  What about any forms of caching?  Is the OOM for the driver or a worker node?

Comment: I'm assuming you use the same `SparkContext` in both jobs, right?

Comment: The jobs themselves have all kinds of problems and are likely to be scrapped shortly, it was intended more of a how-things-work question than trying to debug the issue at hand, which is why I did not post code.  They are sharing a spark-context.  The OOM is coming from the sparkDriver dispatcher so I think but am not certain that it is the workers.